# Change WordPress Post ID Length

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I adjust the unique post ID length assigned to new post types in WordPress?

I'd like to set a minimum limit on this, for example:

your-site.com/?p=258

**Becomes:**

your-site.com/?p=25865487

Having searched, I cannot find any docs/filter or function to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You could simply set the auto-increment value of the posts table to a high starting value … (Whether this makes much sense to begin with, is another question.)

Comment: It's an odd request for sure! Thanks for your comment, I'll test this. Is this not something that is set with the WP core?

Comment: The ID column in the posts table is set as auto_increment, so WP most likely just relies on that, instead of doing anything itself regarding ID creation.

Comment: As alluded to already, these IDs are not random numbers - they start at 1 for your first post, and anything which goes into WordPress' wp_posts table just gets incremented by 1.